# What would be a good, windows and iis (http) based distributed version control system

Tags: http, version-control, distributed

At my job we make & sell websites. Usually we install our .NET C# based site on a customer's server and maintain and support it remotely. However, every once in a while, for bigger development works and just to make things simpler (and faster!), we will copy the site to a local server.

This is great, but has one pain - moving the site back to the customer. Now, If nothing was change on the customer's copy - no problem. However, it is the sad truth that sometime (read more often than I would like) some fixes were needed to be applied on the production server. Either because the customer needed it NOW or simply because it was major bug.

I know that you can easily apply those bug fixes to the local copy as well, but this is an error prone process. So I'm setting my hopes on a distributed version control to help synchronize the two copies.

Here is what I need:

- Easy to install - nothing else needed except the installer and admin rights.
- Can integrated in an existing website as a virtual directory and works on port 80 - no hassle with new DNS required.
- Excellent software

That's it. Any ideas?

---

### Some comments on the answers

First, thanks! much appreciated.

I've looked at Mercurial and  Bazaar and both look very good. The only caveat is the installation as a virtual directory on IIS. Mercurial, as far as I understand, use a special protocol (wire) and Bazaar needs and addition of python extensions. Is there another system which is easier to integrate with IIS? I'm willing to take a performance hit for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at either [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/) or [Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/). I'm told Git also works on windows, but I suspect the windows port is still a second class port at best.

You'll probably need to be able to run python scripts on your webserver to host either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you request but checkout [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which is a windows version of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). You can also read about another rsync solution [here](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-rsync-on-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can also vouch for Mercurial. Simple to use and powerful to boot!